# Is there a way to loadFromLocalStorage and saveToLocalStorage in one useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I manage to make this work with 2 **useEffect** hooks in my functional component":

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('LOAD_FROM_LOCALSTORAGE')
    loadFromLocalStorage({ dispatch })
  }, [])

  useEffect(
    () => {
      console.log('SAVE_TO_LOCALSTORAGE')
      saveToLocalStorage(state)
    },
    [state]
  )
```

There is an egghead.io [tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-store-values-in-localstorage-with-the-react-useeffect-hook) on how to use **localStorage** with **useState** hook but I'm using **useContext** and **useReducer** for app state management.

here's my **loadFromLocalStorage** function:

```
const loadFromLocalStorage = async ({ dispatch }) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = await localStorage.getItem('state')
    if (serializedState === null) return undefined
    const persistedState = await JSON.parse(serializedState)
    await dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_FROM_LOCALSTORAGE', persistedState })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is good point for merging those 2 effects - they are clean now and doing what they were supposed to do, but you can try something like that

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerFunction, {});

useEffect(
    () => {
        // if there is no state 
        if(!Object.keys(state).length) {
            loadFromLocalStorage({ dispatch })
            return;
        }
        saveToLocalStorage(state)
    },
    [state]
)
```